# Speed improvement for Comparing values quicker

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory

I try to compare 2 values out of two different sheets, the rather simple logic here is the value (string2) out of one sheet needs to be at the end of the other value (string1). I try to check this so far with a simple if:

```
If string2 like "*" & string1 then
'do stuff
End if
```

The issue now is that it simply takes too long since every line of sheet 1 needs to be compared with every line of sheet 2. Since these are 4600 and 69.000 Lines, its quite a lot.
Out of the 69.000 Lines, just something like 50 are relevant (match the if-clause).

When I am doing this by hand it's quick and easy, just filter the respecting column and it's not even that much. But checking all these lines with an if clause it simply takes too long.

My logic for going through the sheets is like this:

```
for i= 2 to AmountOfLinesSheet1

string2 = Sheet1.Cells(i, thisColumn).value

for j = 2 to AmountOfLinesSheet2

string1 = Sheet1.Cells(j, thatColumn).value

'here the if check as shown above

next j

next i
```

Is there a way to either improve the if-clause (I would have no idea how) or is there a way to get the comparison quicker or pre-sort it in a way? So maybe, somehow reduce the 69.000 Lines, to only the relevant rows before starting this check?

Comment: "When I am doing this by hand its quick and easy ..." -- you could do that quick and easy thing with the macro recorder turned on and get some ideas from looking at the resulting VBA.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the filter function in vba? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Looping Through Elements of an Array Instead of Cells of a Range

- Depending on the `do stuff`, this should be significantly faster, but it will certainly need more than a second.
- If one match is expected (enough) then `Exit For` in the `If` statement will increase efficiency.
- If one match is expected (enough), most often `Application.Match` instead of the second loop will be used to speed up even more, e.g.:

  ```
  Dim cIndex As Variant: cIndex = Application.Match(string1, Data2, 0)
  If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
      ' do stuff 
  End If
  ```

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    
    Dim Data1 As Variant, Data2 As Variant
    Dim thisColumn As Variant, thatColumn As Variant
    Dim AmountOfLinesSheet1 As Long, AmountOfLinesSheet2 As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim string1 As String, string2 As String
    
    Data1 = Sheet1.Cells(1, thisColumn).Resize(AmountOfLinesSheet1 - 1)
    Data2 = Sheet2.Cells(1, thatColumn).Resize(AmountOfLinesSheet2 - 1)
    
    For i = 2 To AmountOfLinesSheet1
        string1 = Data1(i, 1)
        For j = 2 To AmountOfLinesSheet2
            string2 = Data2(j, 1)
            If string1 Like "*" & string2 Then
            'do stuff
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not IF slow, but getting values from Sheet cells one by one. You should put everything into Array and when do IF checks. It will take a second or less to loop everything :)

```
Dim MyArrayOne As Variant
Dim MyArrayTwo As Variant

MyArrayOne = Sheets(1).Range("A1:V99").Value
MyArraytWO = Sheets(2).Range("A1:V99").Value
```

And when loop through MyArrayOne and MyArrayTwo.